# Purpose of depthwise convolution

Tags: tensorflow

I am curious to know that why we perform depthwise convolution?I understand that it doesn't mix the different channels. But is there any other advantage of this? What benefit I get if I use tf.nn.depthwise over simple conv2d?

```
input = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1,4,4,2]))
filter= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,2,2,1]))
def depth_conv2d(input):
    return tf.nn.depthwise_conv2d(input,filter, strides=[1,2,2,1],padding= 'SAME')
depth_conv_out = depth_conv2d(input)

sess = tf. InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

print depth_conv_out.get_shape()
```